# Hive Expression not in GROUP BY key

Tags: hadoop, hive

i need to execute this query in hive :

```
SELECT 
    waybill_no,
    vehicle_no, 
    WAYBILL_TYPE, 
    etim_no, 
    trip_no, 
    route_no, 
    sum(full_ticket_count) as full_ticket_count, 
    sum(half_ticket_count) as half_ticket_count, 
    sum(BOT_ticket_count) as BOT_ticket_count, 
    sum(manual_ticket_count) as manual_ticket_count, 
    sum(window_booking_count) as window_booking_count, 
    sum(pass_ticket_count) as pass_ticket_count, 
    sum(luggage_ticket_count) as luggage_ticket_count, 
    format((sum(base_fare)/100),2) as base_fare,
    format((sum(asc_amt-ysy_amt)/100),2) as asc_amt,
    format((sum(ysy_amt)/100),2) as ysy_amt, 
    format((sum(bsc)/100),2) as bsc,
    format((sum(toll)/100),2) as toll,
    format((sum(it)/100),2) as it,
    format((sum(sleeper)/100),2) as sleeper,
    format((sum(toll_fee)/100),2) as toll_fee,
    format((sum(bus_stand_fee)/100),2) as bus_stand_fee,
    sum(insp_ticket_count) as insp_ticket_count,
    sum(insp_ticket_amt) as insp_ticket_amt,
    sum(dhaba_collection) as dhaba_collection,
    sum( window_booking) as window_booking,
    format((sum(penalty_amt)/100),2) as penalty_amt,
    format((sum(luggage_amt)/100),2) as luggage_amt, 
    format((sum(total_amount)/100),2) as total_amount,
    format((sum(total_expenses)/100),2) as total_expenses 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        td.waybill_no, 
        td.vehicle_no,
        wb.WAYBILL_TYPE,
        td.etim_no,
        td.trip_no,
        route_no,
        sum( if (ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,full_ticket_count)) as full_ticket_count,
        sum( if (ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,half_ticket_count)) as half_ticket_count,
        sum( if (ticket_code IN('FX','CR'),0,1)) as BOT_ticket_count,
        '0' as manual_ticket_count,
        sum( if (ticket_code='WI',1,0)) as window_booking_count,
        sum( if (ticket_code='PS',(full_ticket_count+half_ticket_count),0)) as pass_ticket_count,
        sum(luggage_ticket_count) as luggage_ticket_count,
        sum( if (td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,((full_ticket_count*adult_basic_fare)+(half_ticket_count*child_basic_fare)))) as base_fare,
        sum( if (td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,((full_ticket_count*td.asc_amt)+(half_ticket_count*td.asc_amt)))) as asc_amt,
        sum( 
            if (
                ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((
                    if(ticket_code IN('WI'),1,full_ticket_count) * state_code_10
                )+(
                    if(ticket_code IN('WI'),0,half_ticket_count)*state_code_10
                ))
            )
        ) as ysy_amt,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,((full_ticket_count*td.bsc_amt)+(half_ticket_count*td.bsc_amt)))) as bsc,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,((full_ticket_count*td.toll_amt)+(half_ticket_count*td.toll_amt)))) as toll,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,((full_ticket_count*td.it_amt)+(half_ticket_count*td.it_amt)))) as it,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,((full_ticket_count*td.sleeper_amt)+(half_ticket_count*td.sleeper_amt)))) as sleeper,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='TO',(td.total_amount),0)) as toll_fee,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='BS',(td.total_amount),0)) as bus_stand_fee,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='IP',full_ticket_count,0)) as insp_ticket_count, 
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='IP',(td.total_amount),0)) as insp_ticket_amt,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='DC',(td.total_amount),0)) as dhaba_collection,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='WI',(td.total_amount),0)) as window_booking,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='PN',(td.total_amount),0)) as penalty_amt,
        sum( if(td.ticket_code='LG',(td.total_amount),0)) as luggage_amt,
        sum( 
            if(
                td.ticket_code IN('TO','BS','FX','CR'),0,td.total_amount
            ) + if(
                ticket_code='PA',adult_basic_fare,0
            ) - if(
                ticket_code='DC',if(docket_no='SBICARD',(total_amount),0),0
            )
        ) as total_amount,
        sum( 
            if(
                td.ticket_code NOT IN('TO','BS','WI'),0,td.total_amount
            )+if(
                td.ticket_code='PA',((full_ticket_count*adult_basic_fare)+(half_ticket_count*child_basic_fare)),0
            )+if(
                e_purse_flag='1',total_amount,0
            )
        ) as total_expenses,
        td.ticket_code
    FROM ticket_data as td
    INNER JOIN waybillprogramming wb on wb.waybill_no=td.waybill_no
    WHERE wb.collection_tm  between str_to_date('2016-07-11 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and str_to_date('2016-07-11 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')   AND td.`ticket_type` != '51'
    GROUP BY wb.waybill_no

    UNION

    SELECT
        wb.waybill_no,
        '' as vehicle_no,
        wb.WAYBILL_TYPE,
        wb.etim_no ,
        '0' as trip_no,
        '0' as route_no,
        '0' as full_ticket_count,
        '0' as half_ticket_count,sum(NO_OF_PASSENGER) as BOT_ticket_count,
        '0' as manual_ticket_count,
        '0' as window_booking_count,
        '0' as pass_ticket_count,
        '0' as luggage_ticket_count,
        '0' as base_fare,
        '0' as asc_amt,
        '0' as ysy_amt,
        '0' as bsc,
        '0' as toll,
        '0' as it,
        '0' as sleeper,
        '0' as toll_fee,
        '0' as bus_stand_fee,
        '0' as insp_ticket_count,
        '0' as insp_ticket_amt,
        '0' as dhaba_collection,
        '0' as window_booking,
        '0' as penalty_amt,
        '0' as luggage_amt,
        ( sum( TICKET_SALE_AMOUNT + RECOVERY_AMT + DHABA_COLLECTION ) * 100 ) as total_amount,
        ( sum( mtc.BRIDGE_FEE + mtc.BUS_STAND_FEE + mtc.REFUND_AMT + mtc.DIESEL_PERCHASED + mtc.OTHER_EXPENSES + mtc.OTHER_BOOKING + mtc.PART_CASH ) * 100 ) as  total_expenses,
        'NN' as ticket_code
    FROM manual_ticket_collection mtc
    INNER JOIN waybillprogramming wb on mtc.WAYBILL_NO = wb.WAYBILL_NO
    WHERE collection_tm between str_to_date('2016-07-11 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and str_to_date('2016-07-11 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
    GROUP BY wb.waybill_no 

    UNION

    SELECT 
        wb.waybill_no,
        '' as vehicle_no,
        wb.WAYBILL_TYPE,
        wb.etim_no,
        '0' as trip_no,
        '0' as route_no,
        '0' as full_ticket_count,
        '0' as half_ticket_count,
        '0' as BOT_ticket_count,
        count(ticket_code) as manual_ticket_count,
        sum(if(ticket_code='WI',(full_ticket+half_ticket),0)) as window_booking_count,
        sum(if(ticket_code='PS',(full_ticket+half_ticket),0)) as pass_ticket_count,
        sum(lugg_ticket) as luggage_ticket_count,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((full_ticket*full_base_fare)+(half_ticket*half_base_fare)))*100) as base_fare,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((full_ticket*mtd.asc_amt)+(half_ticket*mtd.asc_amt)))*100) as asc_amt,
        '0' as ysy_amt,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((full_ticket*mtd.bsc_amt)+(half_ticket*mtd.bsc_amt)))*100) as bsc,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((full_ticket*mtd.toll_amt)+(half_ticket*mtd.toll_amt)))*100) as toll,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((full_ticket*mtd.it_amt)+(half_ticket*mtd.it_amt)))*100) as it,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code IN('TO','BS'),0,((full_ticket*mtd.sleeper_amt)+(half_ticket*mtd.sleeper_amt)))*100) as sleeper,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='TO',(mtd.total_amt),0)) as toll_fee,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='BS',(mtd.total_amt),0)*100) as bus_stand_fee,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='IP',full_ticket,0)) as insp_ticket_count,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='IP',(mtd.total_amt),0)*100) as insp_ticket_amt,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='DC',(mtd.total_amt),0)) as dhaba_collection,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='WI',(mtd.total_amt),0)) as window_booking,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='PN',(mtd.total_amt),0)*100) as penalty_amt,
        sum(if(mtd.ticket_code='LG',(mtd.total_amt),0)*100) as luggage_amt,
        sum(total_amt*100) as total_amount,
        sum((if(ticket_code='TO', total_amt,0)+if(ticket_code='BS', total_amt,0))*100) as total_expenses,
        mtd.ticket_code
    FROM manual_ticket_details mtd
    INNER JOIN waybillprogramming wb on mtd.WAYBILL_NO = wb.WAYBILL_NO
    WHERE collection_tm between str_to_date('2016-07-11 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and str_to_date('2016-07-11 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
    GROUP BY wb.waybill_no
)abc
GROUP BY waybill_no;
```

However i am getting this error when executing the Query

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 35:2 Expression not in
>   GROUP BY key 'waybill_no')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `td.waybill_no` and grouping on `GROUP BY wb.waybill_no` . Since it is an Inner join try selecting `wb.waybill_no`

Comment: that worked however now i am getting this error :
`SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 36:2 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'vehicle_no')`

Comment: You need to read on Group By clauses. When a group by is applied only columns on which rows have been grouped can be selected, in first inner query, i don't see you grouping on td.vehicle_no . It's not a hive thing, it is a simple SQL logic.

Comment: do you mean i will have to add group by for all the columns that i am selecting ?

Comment: this query works in mysql. I am getting these errors when running on hive

Comment: @AngryCoder, yes that is exactly what i mean. You will either have to use aggregate function on selection (like sum, avg) or put all column you select in group by clause. May be it was running in MySql before, because MySql is not strictly SQL compliant.

Comment: Think it this way. If you group by only waybill_no and there are 15 different values of vehicle_no in one group, which one should DB show? And if you know all vehicle_no are going to have same value in one group of waybill_no, I don't see a harm in adding it to group by clause.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the Apache [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+GroupBy#LanguageManualGroupBy-Selectstatementandgroupbyclause) on Hive

---

However, the query below DOES NOT work:

```
SELECT
   a,
   b
FROM
   t1
GROUP BY
   a;
```

This is because the select clause has an additional column (b) that is not included in the group by clause (and it's not an aggregation function either). This is because, if the table t1 looked like:

|   **a**     | **b** |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |

Since the grouping is only done on a, what value of b should Hive display for the group a=100? One can argue that it should be the first value or the lowest value but we all agree that there are multiple possible options. Hive does away with this guessing by making it invalid SQL (HQL, to be precise) to have a column in the select clause that is not included in the group by clause.

---

Think of it as a reduce statement in the MapReduce Paradigm. The aggregate function has to be specified otherwise the column must be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.